# How to "git clone " in Visual studio code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Today, I am following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGOj5yH7evk to learn how to use GitHub, but I using Windows.

I've set it all successfully by also following the official instruction (https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/about-ssh) and it works on Git Bash:
[image]

But I failed when I tried to "git clone" in Visual Studio Code, like what the video does
[image]

I've also tried setting the config because the video mentioned config (although the official instructions don't mention this, which means Windows users don't need to care about this. But this was what I tried to solve the problem, just in case this could make influence on my problem)
[image]

So, is there any requirement for the folder I select to open in VS code to do the git stuff or where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure VSCode is opened with the same user account as the one used in your initial git bash.

In each session (bash and VSCode), execute a:

```
mkdir test
cd test
# Git bash
git -c core.sshCommand='ssh -Tv' clone git@github.com:...
# or, in POwershell
git -c core.sshCommand="ssh -Tv" clone git@github.com:...
```

See if the SSH key is looked into `C:\Users\<You>\.ssh\id_rsa`

Check also if you [have created your private key encrypted with a passphrase](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/129727).

If so, in VSCode, you would need to [enable the SSH agent service](https://gist.github.com/john-auld/a55ffe44e9965623f530cb487e33cebd#enable-the-ssh-agent-service=).

Comment: They both respond "fatal: destination path '...' already exists and is not an empty directory." and I didn't set passphrase, I left them empty

Comment: Yes, I typed  eval "$(ssh-agent -s)",    ssh-add -l -E sha256,    $ ssh-add ~/.ssh/testkey(the name of the keys),  when I set them

Comment: The "ssh -T git@github.com" also said I've successfully authenticated.

Comment: What do you mean by the first sentence? The windows user account? Yes, this is my only account on my computer

Comment: @Ray You need to clone the repository in a new folder, not in the existing parent folder.

Comment: I tried both. A new folder (as the second picture shows) and the parent folder ( C:\Users\username\.ssh ) in the VS Code, but both of them failed

Comment: @Ray With the same error message? ""fatal: destination path"? If you clone in an empty folder, you should not have that error message.

Comment: If I try git clone in a new folder or the parent folder in VS Code, they both response*git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.*

Comment: If I input the command you wrote, in GitBash(parent folder) and VS Code (a new folder or the parent folder), it will respond to me fatal: destination path '...' already exists and is not an empty directory.

Comment: I didn't try to input that command in GitBash for a new folder, because I don't understand. The thing before "$" sign is already Username@LAPTOP-1YQR MINGW64 ~, Does it stay at the top of the directory tree? how do I... I don't know, so I didn't try

Comment: @Ray I have edited the answer to include the creation of a new folder in which you can clone your repository.

Comment: Permission is still denied. I will try to ask for help from near people. Thank you for your help anyway. Maybe the video missed something for instructing in the former part,