# how to do "git clone" on VS code

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

Today, I am following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGOj5yH7evk to learn how to use GitHub, but I am using Windows.

I've set it all successfully by also following the official instruction (https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/about-ssh) and it works on Git Bash.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7f8OE.png)

But I failed when I tried to "git clone" in Visual Studio Code and got this response:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I've also tried setting the config because the video mentioned config (although the official instructions does't mention this, which means Windows users don't need to care about this. But this was what I tried to solve the problem, just in case this could make influence on my problem)

```
file:C:/Users/CC2022/.gitconfig  user.name=CC
file:C:/Users/CC2022/.gitconfig  user.email=username@email.com
file:C:/Users/CC2022/.gitconfig  core.editor='C:\Users\CC2022\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin
```

So, is there any requirement for the folder I select to open in VS code to do the git stuff or where is the problem?

Thank you for your help

Comment: why do you ask the same question after an hour again? You can edit your question. And if you don't get an answer, asking again does not get you an answer, maybe nobody has an answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to "git clone " in Visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73074998/how-to-git-clone-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Haha, that's me, too. Because that was my first time posting a question, I remember I deleted that due to it didn't show pictures directly, it needed to click a link to see pictures like this post. But it was edited by others and  I found it still exists 90 more minutes later. Since someone answered it, I left it there.

Comment: Because I didn't leave the writing page and didn't know the rules here. I clicked to delete it, I don't know why it still exists. But since there was a good guy edited and answer it already, I left it there.

Answer (score 1):

> I can git clone by the HTTP link on both VS code and GitBash, or git clone by the SSH link on Git Bash.
>
> But I have a problem (git clone by SSH link) on VS Code.
> In addition, although git clone by HTTP link on VS Code is okay, but I cannot "push" edited files back to GitHub, because the access is denied

That means the repository you are trying to push back to is not one you own/have created. You might therefore have no right to contribute back to it directly.